# Best setup for a portable studio?

Tags: audio-recording, home-studio

I've often needed to record while at a musicians house/studio/practice-pad (same goes for podcasting on the fly). To do so I needed my studio (or part of it) to be very mobile. I always want to achieve the highest quality sound as possible so it doesn't sound like a portable studio.

What is the best setup for a small, extremely portable studio? (thinking single mic, etc). I currently produce hip hop, electronica as well as do some screencasting/podcasting.

I should note that my current set up for mobile recording is as follows:

**General Recording**

- Laptop with a DAW
- M-Audio Mobile-Pre
- Condenser Mic
- MPC1000 and/or Akai LPK25 MIDI Controller

**Podcasting**

- Snowglobe Mic (set up for omni directional)
- Laptop with DAW

**Screencasting**

- Laptop w/ Camtasia (for MAC and PC)
- Snowglobe

Any additional tips/tricks would be appreciated.

Comment: You should move the info from your "answer" below up to the question.

Answer (score 5):

I've done almost exclusively mobile recording for the past few years (simply because I have no space where I live to have bands over).  It's been mostly rock bans.  Here's some general things I've found to be useful:

- **More smaller racks, rather than fewer huge racks**
- **Rack cases with wheels** (SKB makes a great version)
- **Ability to support multiple headphones with different mixes.**  *CRUCIAL* if you are recording more than one person at a time
- **Duplicate of crucial cables** - firewire, optical, etc.  Anything that, if it breaks, your entire system won't work
- **Set up your session template files in advance, including sends/etc.**
- **Case contents organized by item type**, e.g. all mics in one case, cables in another.  Again, many smaller cases are better than fewer huge ones, both for your back and for getting in/out of tight spaces
- **Cable ties** - avoid tangles; nothing's more annoying than having your musicians watch you untangle cables.
- **Color tape your cables and bring multi-color tape with you** - you're most likely going to be using the musicians you are recording as assistant engineers, so keeping things obvious and simple for communication wil help

Comment: +1 for color tape.  Never a fun experience once you realise you are hearing left what should be right AFTER you set everything up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the quality or portability you are trying to achieve, but if you want to go on the super-small, super-easy end, check out one of the many portable handheld recorders.

I use a [Zoom H4n](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h4n/), as the built-in stereo pair of mics aren't bad, and I can use the jacks on the bottom to hook up additional mics or take a line-in from a board.  I haven't used it, but I assume their [H2 with 4 built-in mics](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h2/) for getting nice surround recording is good too.

There are also all-in-one rigs with a mixer, preamps, and editing all in one package.  Roland pioneered this awhile back.  Zoom makes the [R24](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/r24/index.php), but again, I don't know about it's quality.  It just came out recently.  This will allow you to capture a performance, and you can edit later.

However, if you are looking for a more robust solution, davetron5000's suggestions are best.  I also second SKB cases, they are quite awesome.